# access SD card data on IP camera with ONVIF on python

Tags: python, sd-card, ip-camera, onvif, python-onvif

I a m trying to access the SD card of my IP camera in a remote way.

I figure out that it may be possible to do that with ONVIF under python: https://github.com/quatanium/python-onvif

The set of functions available is here https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/util/operationIndex.html.

I can easily use the ones under `DeviceMgmt` by calling `mycam.devicemgmt` or the ones under `PTZ`  by calling first `ptz=mycam.create_ptz_service()` and then `mycam.ptz`. I am not so sure about this difference by the way.

However if I tried to do the same with `Recording` (with I guess the functions allowing to get SD card data), but it does not work.

I ran `mycam.devicemgmt.GetCapabilities()` and can see that `PTZ` and `Recording` are not "organized" in the same way (see below) because in the structure `PTZ` is "acessible" directly while recording is under something caleed `Extension` with a set of different "functions" like `DeviceIO`.

How can I use the the `Recording` functions, what should be the python syntax?

```
{
    'PTZ': {
        'XAddr': 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/onvif/PTZ',
        '_value_1': None,
        '_attr_1': None
    },
    'Extension': {
        '_value_1': [
            <Element {http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema}DeviceIO at 0x2722de89f00>,
            <Element {http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema}Recording at 0x2722de89ec0>,
            <Element {http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema}Search at 0x2722de89e40>,
            <Element {http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema}Replay at 0x2722de89f40>
        ]
}
```